# Making a webpage with mostly javascript/dojo in django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, json, dojo

I'm using django and its template system.  After dealing with it for a while, I kind of felt that it was a pain to edit a template if I'd have to change a view significantly or to deal with the organization of template modularity.  I'm sure many of you do not agree with this assessment.  Anyhow, I want to instead let each view send a JSON object to the client and using javascript/dojo on the client side, render the whole website.  Of course the views will still be organized django style and I'll have to organize the JSON appropriately.

I realize there maybe some performance issues with this.  At the same time, I'm also worried about the load time(synchronous) that might occur due to loading all the javascript and then the json, and then finally the html.  But perhaps a good algorithm in the way a page is rendered could help mitigate these issues, perhaps sort of like lazy loader.  Either way, could this design possibly work out well?

Comment: it will work, but that depends on how you **design** the architecture of your site. poor planning can cost you a lot of time. better plan out how you do pages, how to swap between them, how you do logins, ACL, caching and stuff. Google it, it's a lot to cover.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of applications that are designed this way - and most of the performance (both positive and negative) comes from the strength of the javascript library used and as you guessed, how it handles deferred loading and caching.

The [django-extjs](http://django-extjs.demo.revolunet.com/) project does this with the <strike>extjs</strike> sencha library. You could get some inspiration from there, or simply use it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of this design pattern in "[Mastering Dojo](http://pragprog.com/book/rgdojo/mastering-dojo)". Actually the whole book advises us to do sites this way **when it comes to rich internet applications**. Maybe it's a bit overkill for a regular website with different pages though.

I tried their examples and the way they do it performs very well in my machine. Basically, the idea is to separate the data that fills your widgets from the metadata (i.e. the information about the way widgets are layed out in your page - styles, positions, etc...).

Schematically (from the book), you would end-up with a few functions that are parallelized through deferreds/promises, like :

```
function init() { // initialize global variables }

function getData() { // retrieve data from the server }

function getMetaData() { // retrieve metadata from the server }

function continueWithData() { // push data into cache }

function continueWithMetadata() { // prepare panel with HTML controls, etc. }

function finish() { // Push data into HTML controls and release the panel to the user }
```

These functions are chained in this way :

```
  init()
    |
    v
 -----------------------------------------------
    |                             |
    v                             v
 getData()                     getMetadata()
    |                             |
    v                             v
continueWithData()              continueWithMetadata()
    |                             |
    v                             v
  ----------------------------------------------
                     |
                     v
                   finish()
```

My apologies for copying the book schema - I hope I'm not enfringing any copyright stuff, and there may be better patterns out there on blogs, but I really like the way it is explained there, so...

The whole parallelism is implemented through dojo.Deferreds. I think it's easier now with [dojo.when/dojo.then](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/promises/), so you may give it a try...